# MacBook Air Early 2015 Black Screen Repeated Chime, boot key combo does not work, Can this MacBook be recovered?

Tags: macos, macbook, laptop-repair, black-screen-of-death, macbook-air

First of all, sorry for my bad English.

So, my MacBook Air A1465 suddenly fell into a deep 'coma.'

Now, the MacBook cannot be turned on. It's just a blank black screen with a repeating chime.

I did the SMC reset and PRAM Reset, etc. but nothing worked. Also, I cannot use any boot key combination (except for SMC and PRAM Reset).

What happened before this?

When I was doing some work, the MacBook shut down when the battery level was at around 20%.

I thought it might be just the battery os too low.

I grabbed the MagSafe, and plugged it in. The charger light comes on, and I left it like that for a few minutes.

Then I opened the clamshell, and pressed the power button.

Nothing, just black screen. Thinking that maybe it just needs time to boot, I leave it alone. a few minutes later I come back and the screen was still black and the fan was spinning so %#*@ loud. I then pressed the power button to force it to shut down.

Then I tried to boot into safe mode, it sometimes works (I am able to get into the OS in safe mode) but sometimes it just doesn’t work, like the shift button doesn't even respond when I pressed it while the mac is starting up.

Tried the SMC reset and PRAM reset, but nothing has any noticeable effect. Still just a black screen and repeating chime.

When I was finally able to boot into the macOS, the first thing I did was updating the operating system from macOS Sierra to High Sierra (Thinking that maybe it's because of an old OS that needs updating).

But no, the problem was still there. When I closed the clamshell and open it again, the black screen was back.

Then I thought, maybe I should clean install the macOS. So I did. I grabbed a USB Stick and made a bootable USB.

Using Disk Utility, I formatted the SSD and proceeded to clean install macOS High Sierra.

The first time it rebooted, I can see the Apple logo and the progress bar, but nothing else. The progress bar doesn’t move, the Apple logo stays there for hours. So I again pressed the power button to shut it down.

Long story short, now the MacBook is completely dead, I can no longer able to boot the USB, can't get into diagnostics, CMD+R doesn't work, nothing.

All of the boot key combos don’t work. I tried every single combination and every single way of pressing it, nothing.

What is the possible status of this MacBook?

Is it the EFI Chip and/or the EFI Firmware that is corrupt? Or is it the RAM? Processor? GPU? Or an hardware issue?

Can I recover this MacBook? At this point, I am willing to even try buying the new EFI Chip, but before I do that, I just want to narrow the cause of this down.

Can anyone help me to guide me in the right direction without involving Apple Store? (Because in my place there is no way I could find an Apple Store or Genius Bar.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you boot in Single User Mode, by pressing the Command and S keys simultaneously on startup until you see white lettering on the black screen and a prompt to enter commands? In recent macOS versions, it's hit-or-miss when it comes to Single User mode being available or not, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But, I already try to boot into Single User Mode, Safe Mode, Verbose Mode. None of the boot key works. Including the CMD+R for boot from recovery.

Comment: Can you lay your hands on a macOS ISO, burn it onto a USB drive (or DVD if you have an external DVD player with a USB-C adapter; they're hard to come by these days, but who knows) and try to boot from the removable device. Once there (fingers crossed), you'll be able to fix what's broken. Could also be that the screen is faulty, in which case you won't be able to do much. If it's the battery, and you can remove it without tearing the whole thing apart, you can try and boot with MagSafe on, battery out. It'll only throttle the CPU down, but it'll work.

Comment: Hi again. I did try to clean install the macOS using USB Stick, but I can not get into the boot option by holding the ALT key during boot up. I did try to turn it on without the battery, same result. As for the screen being faulty, I don't think it is because if it is the screen, the caps lock light will still lit when I press it, I think. But I will try to connect external monitor when I could get the dongle.

Comment: The screen on your laptop is backlit, and if backlighting is cooked, then your screen just doesn't display anything, though maybe your machine is up and running, so it's worth a try hooking it up with an external monitor. Not being able to boot from the USB stick is another matter. How did you burn the ISO on the stick?

Comment: I know, but if the problem is just with the screen, then the bootup chime will be normal, it will not repeat every few seconds on an infinite loop. also if it is booting normally and I just can not see anything due to the screen being dead, then the keyboard should still work I mean when I press the caps lock button, the led indicator will be on. But in my case, it is not. I created the USB bootable using my friends MacBook air, using the Terminal Method. Also if the problem is on the USB Stick then The other boot key combo still gonna work, i.e. boot from internet recovery. I think.

Comment: Worth a try, but I hadn't caught on the chime thing. If it's repeated every few seconds, it means your Mac didn't pass POST. Among the sounds here (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202768), which one is it?

Comment: Yeah, as soon as I have access to the display dongle I will try to connect it to external monitor. as for the tone, there is no tone like on the apple support website. By tone, I believe they mean tone like "beeb", not a startup chime. and there is no tone.  if by tones they mean startup chime, then the closest thing is this one "One tone, repeating every five seconds".

Comment: According to Apple's own litterature, this means you've got a problem with your RAM, and if I'm not mistaken, on this model, RAM is soldered to the logic board, so your best hope is to bring it a shop that caters to Apple Care somehow, or to a Genius Bar nearby. You could try to repair it yourself, but it could get messy...